# How to convert a varchar 'DDMMYYYY HH:MM:SS' into DATETIME in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a `varchar` column that has the date in this format

```
DDMMYYYY HH:MM:SS
```

For example, `30072016 23:59:59` and I need to insert this into a `DATETIME` column in another table.

I tried various `convert` options and all seem to give this error

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted
>   in an out-of-range value

Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way using `CONVERT` function with *style* `105`

```
DECLARE @datetime varchar(50)='30072016 23:59:59'
SELECT CONVERT(datetime,stuff(stuff(@datetime,3,0,'-'),6,0,'-'),105)
```

Since your current datetime format does not match with any of the native datetime formats in `SQL SERVER` so we need to convert to a format that sql server can read.

`SQL SERVER` can read this format `DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS`. To insert `-` between `day`, `month` and `year` use [**`STUFF`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx) function. After inserting we can convert it to `datetime`

Comment: This seems to work.!! Can you explain this? Just trying to learn!! And also, It introduces milliseconds part which I dont need..? how to remove?

Comment: Read about `stuff` function which puts string into another string. Read about `datetime` for the second part of your comment. Everything is documented.

Comment: @Rohinibaskaran - Added explanation.. Dont worry about millisecond since it is not present in your current format. It will be always zero.

Answer (score 2):

One method in SQL Server 2012+ would be to do the date and time conversion separately:

```
select (datefromparts(substring(col, 5, 4) + 0, substring(col, 3, 2) + 0, left(col, 2)) +
        convert(time, right(col, 8))
       ) as dt_value
```

Actually, this can work in earlier versions, you just need to use a different function because `datefromparts()` is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

This does not match any format natively parsable by SQL Server.

Thus, my suggestion would be to:

- use string manipulation (`LEFT` and `SUBSTRING`) to convert it into a format which *is* natively parsable by SQL Server, for example, `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` (style 120, "ODBC canonical"),
- and then use `CONVERT` to convert it to a datetime.